# didSelectRowAtIndexPath not called after disabling @objc Inference (Xode 9, Swift 4)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, xcode9

I am updating a project from Swift 3 to Swift 4, in Xcode 9.

In the migration process, when it asks me to chose "Swift 4 `@objc` Inference", I select "Minimize Inference (recommended)".

Then I follow all the steps from the Xcode Help page titled "Migrate to Swift 4 `@objc` inference", paragraph "Completing a Swift 4 minimize inference migration".

After completing the last two steps ("Open the build settings for the project.; Set Swift 3 `@objc` inference to Default."), suddenly `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not called in my app. There is no error or warning, it's simply not called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr:
Turns out I needed to mark as `@objc` the class extension in which the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` was defined.

Details:

Note that whereas in most cases the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is defined in the class extension that is used to conform to the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol, my setup was different because of inheritance:

I have a `ParentVC` and a `ChildVC`. `ParentVC` is conforming to `UITableViewDelegate` via a class extension (this approach is mentioned in Apple's "The Swift Programming Language (Swift 4)", under "Adding Protocol Conformance with an Extension"). The `ParentVC` implements some `UITableViewDelegate` methods, but does not implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

The `ChildVC` is where `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is actually implemented. This is done in a class extension (of `ChildVC`), but note that this class extension does not contain the conformance (`: UITableViewDelegate`) (`ParentVC` already does this and trying to also do it in `ChildVC` would cause the "Redundant conformance" error).

So adding the `@objc` to the class extension in `ChildVC` solved the problem.

Not sure if this is a bug in Swift/Xcode/compiler/analyzer (maybe at least a warning is in order?), or whether the approach I'm using for protocol conformance + inheritance is flawed, would love to hear others' take on this.